# How to implement automation of routine tasks in the browser in Swift language in Xcode?

Tags: ios, swift, macos

I need help with an explanation, here there is a routine process in the browser due to a mouse click, you need to insert the name of the csv file in the search, then click on a special button, then import and import it, search by search already from a folder on the desktop, for example, and so need 1500 files, takes 40 hours. I want to automate this process, but due to Swift, maybe there are analogues, I know - "ZennoPoster" is only one of them, but I want to do it in Xcode and Swift as the first project and experience! So I ask the specialists for help, how can this be realized !?

Comment: Does this help: https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/1117/how-to-implement-a-file-and-directory-picker-in-macos-using-swift-5